# Problem with Chapter heading styles

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters

Can you please help with this problem. Well, i try to make my chapter's heading more intersting and I found a style that I like from Vincent Zoonekynd’s web-page, http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html.

However, when I compile this code, it gives an error: `file psboxit.sty not found`.

Thank you in advance

```
\documentclass{12pt,a4paper,book}
\usepackage{psboxit,pstcol}
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \reset@font
  \parindent \z@ 
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  \hbox{%
    \vbox{%
      \hsize=2cm%
      \begin{tabular}{c}
        \scshape \strut \@chapapp{} \\
        \psboxit{box 0 0 0 setrgbcolor fill}{%
          \vrule depth 8em width 0pt%
          \vrule height 0pt depth 0pt width 10pt%
          {\white \LARGE \bfseries 
            \strut \vrule height 1em depth 0pt width 0pt
            \thechapter}%
          \vrule height 0pt depth 0pt width 10pt%
          }
      \end{tabular}%
      }%
    \vbox{%
      \advance\hsize by -2cm
      \hrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width \hsize
      \par
      \vskip 6pt%
      \hspace{20pt}%
      \parbox{260pt}{%
        \Huge \bfseries #1}%
      }%
    }%
  \vskip 100\p@
}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \reset@font
  \parindent \z@ 
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  \hbox{%
    \vbox{%
      \hsize=2cm%
      \begin{tabular}{c}
        \scshape \strut \phantom{\@chapapp{}} \\
        \psboxit{box 0 0 0 setrgbcolor fill}{%
          \vrule depth 8em width 0pt%
          \vrule height 0pt depth 0pt width 10pt%
          {\white \LARGE \bfseries 
            \strut \vrule height 1em depth 0pt width 0pt
            \vphantom{\thechapter}}%
          \vrule height 0pt depth 0pt width 10pt%
          }
      \end{tabular}%
      }%
    \vbox{%
      \advance\hsize by -2cm
      \hrule height 0.4pt depth 0pt width \hsize
      \par
      \vskip 6pt%
      \hspace{20pt}%
      \parbox{260pt}{%
        \Huge \bfseries #1}%
      }%
    }%
  \vskip 100\p@
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your first line should probably be `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}`. The package `psboxit` seems to be outdated. Anyways, as the error tells you, you obviously don’t have it installed. You could download it from CTAN and put it in your working directory. As the package is quite old you could try to solve your problem using `pstricks` maybe. Or you could have a look at the package `titlesec`.

Comment: Thank you for your respinse. I tried to find it in CTAN but i didn't succeed

Comment: Just one strike of Google: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/psboxit .

Comment: I actually found this one but i could not upload it. I don't kniw why???

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but maybe a starting point for the wanted format using `titlesec`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,calc,xcolor,lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries}{}{0pt}%
  {\raisebox{-5mm}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \begin{minipage}{20mm}
      \centering{\mdseries\footnotesize\textsc{Chapitre}}\\[2pt]%
      \rule{10mm}{30mm}\hspace{-10mm}%
      \raisebox{25mm}{\parbox{10mm}{\centering\textcolor{white}{\thechapter}}}%
    \end{minipage}}%
  \rule{\textwidth-20mm}{.4pt}\\%
  \hspace*{25mm}}[\vspace*{10mm}]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit:**

You may want to add a separate format for numberless chapter-like titles:

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}\\%
  \hspace*{5mm}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its perfect for me. I will try it in my tex. Thznk you you are the best.

Comment: I tried your code. The rrsult was good however it was applied even for the table contents and the abstract and aknowledgement. I just want it for the chapters because for abstract i did \ chapter*{abstract} .......how can i fix that N.B my thesis is in frensh . thank you

Comment: See my edit. You may add a separate formate for “chapters” that are numberless.

Comment: I got a warning " font shape T1 lmr bx sc undefined font using T1/lmr/bx/n instead ????

Comment: It means that you don’t have a font that is both bold and has small caps. It will be replaced by the regular bold font.

Comment: So i will just let it be or i need to change the font ? And thank you again im new to latex so i appreciate your help thank you

Comment: It is just a warning. If you don’t mind that small caps are replaced by bold, than you can just ignore it. If you do mind, you should use another font that you like. I just changed the order of some commands in the line where it says “Chapitre”, maybe the warning was due to that.

Comment: You are absolutly right thank you so muchhhhhh. The warning has gone with the change you have made. You are the bestttt i really do appreciate your help. Thank youuuu so much. Wish u all the best